# Time calculation from textbox values (not DateTimes), returning quarters of hour

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a few issues:

-I need to perform a calculation using military times input into two textboxes by the user.  The return should read 2.25 hours, 2.75 hours, etc, down to the quarter hour.

-The return provided by my current calculation is returning a formatting error onsubmit.

I have a form in which I need to calculate the difference in hours between a start-time and an end-time, input in military (24-hour) time.  Employees are paid in quarter-hour time intervals, therefore the return needs to be in number of hours, down to the quarter-hour (i.e.  4.25 hrs, 4.75 hrs, etc).

Due to the formatting of the form, the start-date and start-time as well as the end-date and end-time are in different textboxes.  On top of this, not all browsers support an input type="time", so I can't use it to simplify the calculation and have instead used textboxes with type="number".

The relevant asp is as follows:

```
<label for="tbBeginningTime">beginning time</label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbBeginningTime" type="number" AllowNegatives="false" onblur="javascript:hoursCalc();"></asp:TextBox>

<label for="tbEndingTime">ending time</label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbEndingTime" type="number" AllowNegatives="false" onblur="javascript:hoursCalc();"></asp:TextBox>

<label for="tbTotalTime">total time</label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbTotalTime" type="number" ReadOnly="true" AllowNegatives="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

I've used Javascript to perform a simple calculation to determine the number of hours, however I have been unsuccessful at separating the decimal place out and calculating the quarter-hour (.25, .50, .75).  I've tried to separate out the decimal places in a modulus, and I've tried splitting them into an array, but none of that provided the correct return in the tbTotalTime textbox.

The relelvant javascript is as follows

```
function hoursCalc () {
        var startTime = document.getElementById('<%= tbBeginningTime.ClientID %>');
        var endTime = document.getElementById('<%= tbEndingTime.ClientID %>');
        var totalTime = document.getElementById('<%= tbTotalTime.ClientID %>');
        var t1 = 0;
        var t2 = 0;

        if (startTime.value != "") t1 = startTime.value;
        if (endTime.value != "") t2 = endTime.value;

        if (endTime.value < startTime.value) t2 = parseInt(endTime.value) + 2400;

        totalTime.value = parseInt((parseInt(t2) - parseInt(t1)) / 100);
    }
```

This calculates the number of hours and places it in the tbTotalTime textbox, however when I try to submit the form using a parameterized SQL insert statment, I receive an error stating "Input string was not in a correct format."

here is the c# i'm using:

```
protected void btnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimeHubDBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertRequestCO", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BeginningTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(tbBeginningTime.Text, "HHmm", null).TimeOfDay;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndingTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(tbEndingTime.Text, "HHmm", null).TimeOfDay;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalTime", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(tbTotalTime.Text);

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                SuccessMessage = "Request Saved Successfully";
                DisplaySuccessDialog(null, null);

                ConfigureButtons(null, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PopupTitle = "Save Error: ";
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                DisplayErrorDialog(null, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

I know I'm probably going to get a few down-votes for such a convoluted question, but I'm at a loss.  I'm open to any suggestions anyone has in order to make this process smoother.

Answer (score 0):

> I receive an error stating "Input string was not in a correct
>   format."

You are getting this error because you are trying to pass some value to some method, but the value you pass is different than the one which the method expects.

If you put breakpoints in your button click code, you can see that you are getting error in this line.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalTime", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(tbTotalTime.Text);
```

Your error is specifically in the `int.Parse(tbTotalTime.Text)` part. `int.Parse` function is expecting a string which can be convrted to an integer value (Ex :"3"). But when you execute your code, you are getting an empty string and `int.Parse` is failing to convert the empty string to a valid numeric value.

Even though your javascript is setting the value to your field, It is not available in your sever code. This is because of the viewstate. You need to disable view state for this field and that should fix your problem.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbTotalTime" type="number" EnableViewState="false"
                                                    AllowNegatives="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Going further, any time you get any errors, try to put break points in your code and debug. This will help you to understand which part of code is failing. You can inspect the variable values etc while debugging.